# Load all images from folder in Android

Tags: java, android, gridview

I would like to load all images in a folder without knowing the names of the files and store them into a Integer vector - at runtime.

In fact, i need the same as it is done in this example:
 http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html
But at runtime and without knowing the names of the files.

Any help?

---

After your answers i know how to do it... but i dont know how to go on in the same way as the example:

How could i keep the images in an integer array instead of an drawable array or similar?. Here is my try with drawable: DrawArray[i] = Drawable.createFromPath(fileArray[i].getPath());
But i would like to do it with integer to fit with the link above!

Thanks in advance

---

**GENERAL SOLUTION:** http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?t=575

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get all files of a specific folder, use the [`list()`-method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list%28%29) of the `File`-class, which lists all Files of the specified directory.

To create a Bitmap (which can then be drawn), you can use the [`BitmapFactory`-class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html).

After that, you'll need to create your own Adapter (as shown in the linked tutorial) to show your Bitmaps.

Comment: How could i keep the images in an integer array instead of an drawable array or similar?. Here is my try with drawable: DrawArray[i] = Drawable.createFromPath(fileArray[i].getPath()); But i would like to do it with integer to fit with the link above!

Comment: If the images are not in the `/res/drawable`-folder, there is no way of doing this.

Comment: You can't create sub-folders in `res/drawable`.

Answer (score 9):

Using some of the code from the following topic:

[Load and display all the images from a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300847/load-and-display-all-the-images-from-a-folder)

You can use a standard way, such as:

```
// array of supported extensions (use a List if you prefer)
    static final String[] EXTENSIONS = new String[]{
        "gif", "png", "bmp" // and other formats you need
    };
    // filter to identify images based on their extensions
   static final FilenameFilter IMAGE_FILTER = new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(final File dir, final String name) {
        for (final String ext : EXTENSIONS) {
            if (name.endsWith("." + ext)) {
                return (true);
            }
        }
        return (false);
    }
   };
```

and then use is it as so:

```
{
    ....
    File dir = new File(dirPath);
    File[] filelist = dir.listFiles(IMAGE_FILTER );
    for (File f : filelist)
    { // do your stuff here }
    ....
 }
```

Comment: where is the "image" type filter?

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300847/load-and-display-all-the-images-from-a-folder

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [File](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29) class and it's listFiles() method to return a list of all image files in a given location. From there just take that list and construct your adapter from there.