# How to get images from a folder in the server using Jersey WS?

Tags: java, web-services, web, jersey

I am learning the Jersey web services, now I understood how GET and POST work :

```
 @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getHandler() {
        return "<h1>Get some REST!<h1>";
    }

@POST
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String postHandler(String content) {
    return content;
}
```

in Jersey Documentation for featching images it said :

```
@GET
@Path("/images/{image}")
@Produces("image/*")
public Response getImage(@PathParam("image") String image) {
  if (!isSafeToOpenFile(image)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot open the image file.");
  }

  File f = new File(image);

  if (!f.exists()) {
    throw new WebApplicationException(404);
  }

  String mt = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f);
  return Response.ok(f, mt).build();
}
```

I would appreciated if you can show me an example using the above code to fetch images from a folder in the server and post them in a html.
Thanks lot.

Comment: "post them in a html" ? don't you mean "get them from a html" ?

Comment: No, I meant how to get them from server side (using jersey ws) .

Comment: I want to get images to be displayed in a page, but displaying the latest first using jersey web services. Thanks

Comment: getImage() service serves just one image at a time. If you need to display several images in a given order, then this must be done in the html page you build dynamically (using JSP, JSF facelet or servlet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full example of a live gallery, based on REST services.

**REST services (Jersey)**

This service gives the content (filenames) of the image server directory (here `C:\Temp\hotfolder`).

```
    // array of supported extensions 
    static final String[] EXTENSIONS = new String[] { "jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "bmp" };

    // filter to identify images based on their extensions
    static final FilenameFilter IMAGE_FILTER = new FilenameFilter() {

        @Override
        public boolean accept(final File dir, final String name) {
            for (final String ext : EXTENSIONS) {
                if (name.endsWith("." + ext)) {
                    return (true);
                }
            }
            return (false);
        }
    };

    @GET
    @Path("folderImages")
    @Produces("text/json")
    public Response getFolderImages(@QueryParam("lastknown") String lastknown) 
    {
        //Gets the contents of the folder (reverse order : more recent first)
        //see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300847/load-and-display-all-the-images-from-a-folder
        File dir = new File("C:\\Temp\\hotfolder");
        File [] files = dir.listFiles(IMAGE_FILTER); 
        Arrays.sort( files, new Comparator<File>() {
            public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                if (f1.lastModified() > f2.lastModified()) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (f1.lastModified() < f2.lastModified()) {
                    return +1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        });
        //Fills a list (from the more recent one, until the last known file)
        ArrayList<String> newfiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (File f : files)
        {
            if (lastknown!=null && f.getName().equals(lastknown)) 
                break;
            newfiles.add(f.getName());
        }
        //Answers the list as a JSON array (using google-gson, but could be done manually here)
        return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(new Gson().toJson(newfiles)).type("text/json").build();
    }
```

Also this is the image service, needed for rendering each image individually.

```
    @GET
    @Path("/images/{image}")
    @Produces("image/*")
    public Response getImage(@PathParam("image") String image) {
      File f = new File("C:\\Temp\\hotfolder\\" + image);
      if (!f.exists()) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(404);
      }
      String mt = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f);
      return Response.ok(f, mt).build();
    }
```

**gallery.html**

Html, with a little help of JQuery. This HTML polls every 5 seconds, asking for service if there is new files (more recent) than the last file known. Et voilà!

You can notice we are using the jquery `.prepend` method to insert images dynamically at the beginning of the gallery div.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Folder demo</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Live gallery</h1>
    <div id="gallery1" style="border:1px solid black;padding:10px;"></div>
    <div id="info1"></div>
<script>
var counter = 0; 
var lastknown = ""; 
function doPoll(){
$.get('rest/folderImages?lastknown='+lastknown, function(data) {
    counter++;
    $("#info1").html("<pre>Counter: " + counter + "<br>New files: " + data + "</pre>");
    for (var i=data.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        $("#gallery1").prepend("<img src=\"rest/images/" + data[i] + "\" style=\"width:200px;height:200px\" />");
        lastknown = data[i];
    }
    setTimeout(doPoll,5000);
    });
}
$(document).ready( doPoll );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: With this code, only newer files appears. Deleted files are not removed from the client gallery (until next full page refresh, ie F5 on browser). Code can be simpler if you refresh the whole galery contents at once. Browser will not flicker (because of already loaded images in the browser cache).

Comment: Thanks lot, I have a question please : what are : Status.OK and IMAGE_FILTER ? Thanks

Comment: For the missing `IMAGE_FILTER` code fragment see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300847/load-and-display-all-the-images-from-a-folder). `Status.OK` means 200, and refers to `javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status` (in eclipse, use Shift+Ctrl+O to organize imports).

Comment: Thank you Stephane, I appreciate your help. now when I go to the browser and type the url :  http://localhost:8081/RESTfulWebserviceExample/rest/ConversionService/folderImages  , I got  an array : ["pic1.jpg","pic2.jpg,....], BUT when I go to the html file in the browser : http://localhost:8081/RESTfulWebserviceExample/lastImages.html , the div is blank, and the console show :   GET http://localhost:8081/rest/ConversionService/folderImages?lastknown= 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It seems you've a misplaced slash at the beginning of your ajax $.get call : `$.get('rest/ConversionService/folderImages` (no / needed at the begining, else your service url is not relative but absolute)

Comment: Thanks Stephane, now I can see image placeholders in the page, the console says for all the images :   GET http://localhost:8081/RESTfulWebserviceExample/rest/images/6.png 404 (Not Found) , in java service I have :   File dir = new File("/Users/majid/Documents/workspaceRest/RESTfulWebserviceExample/Temp/hotfolder");

Comment: I guess the dynamically generated `img` elements refers to a bad URL. In your case, you should have something like `img src=\"rest/ConversionService/images/"` (in my webapp, my service is just `rest/*`, your is `rest/ConversionService/*`)

Comment: I have already did : img src=\"rest/ConversionService/images/" , but still not working.

Comment: Test the image service independently. Do your browser displays something at URL: `localhost:8081/RESTfulWebservice/rest/ConversionService/images/pic1.jpg` ? If not, check the getImage @path (this url should access the getImage service method. Add traces to check that the getImage function is called.)

Comment: I have an exception in getImage method :  File f = new File("/Users/majid/Documents/workspaceRest/RESTfulWebserviceExample/Temp/hotfolder" + image);
        if (!f.exists()) {                           if (!f.exists()) {
         System.out.println("404");
          throw new WebApplicationException(404);

Comment: You're missing a "/" after hotfolder, so your concatenated filename is "/Users/majid/Documents/workspaceRest/RESTfulWebserviceExample/Temp/hotfold‌​erpic1.jpg". Add a trailing slash to the directory name : `File f = new File("/Users/majid/Documents/workspaceRest/RESTfulWebserviceExample/Temp/hotfold‌​er/" + image);`

Comment: Thanks, everything is working now, in your case what the counter in the div info was there for ? it keep incrementing for ever .

Comment: Counter and info just made for debug purposes. You can remove them :)

Comment: Thanks lot Stephane, I learned lot from you, I appreciate, if you don't mind, here is my email akramakom at gmail dot com, I was wondering if we want to save and display some meta data with the images, the same line pintrest site, any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Jersey example from documentation is clear enough to me. However, here is a simplified example without parameters (do simple to begin...)

```
@GET
@Path("/images/pet")
@Produces("image/*")
public Response getImage() {
  File f = new File("C:\\\\Temp\\dog.jpg");
  if (!f.exists()) {
    throw new WebApplicationException(404);
  }
  String mt = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(f);
  return Response.ok(f, mt).build();
}
```

As my Jersey is configured as `/rest/*` path in the *web.xml* of the *yourapp* application, the image is accessible at the following address:

`http://serverip:port/yourapp/rest/images/pet`

You can try it directly this URL in the browser navigation bar (it is a REST image service, served as if it was a static image), or if you want it in a html page, you can use classic HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Woof!</h1>
    <img src="http://localhost:8080/myapp/rest/images/pet" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

Okay that was too obvious. So you need to implement a method or service that gives the content of a directory with image file names in the given order you need (as a java List).

Using this List, you can build a html like this within a loop:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Several images</h1>
    <img src="/yourapp/rest/images/last.jpg" /><br/>
    <img src="/yourapp/rest/images/third.jpg" /><br/>
    <img src="/yourapp/rest/images/second.jpg" /><br/>
    <img src="/yourapp/rest/images/first.jpg" /><br/>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the result HTML you must output (in JSP or whatever you use). The REST service getImage() will be called automatically by the browser, once for each image.

Am I clear ?

Comment: Thank you Stephan, that was the idea, but if the image folder has lot of images, and they are changing all the time, I would like to iterate them in jsp using a jstl or some jquery things, The problem here is not how to display them, I am just wondering if there is a way to get images (how to implement it) dynamically from server, and I want the latest images uploaded to be displayed.

Comment: OK. If the number of files is very huge, you must do some paging (ie display the nth more recent on page 1). For live updating, you need ajax (JQuery...) calling a file service (rest/jersey if you want) that serves the new filenames since the last call. You must use a "mark" (for example the last filename) for the service to know what images file name the client ever knows on its side. A simpler way would be to refresh the whole page (assuming paging). You can also imagine a service that renders text/html, and use jquery to replace it at once with $('#gallery').html(...);