# Display Images from Folder using java

Tags: java, image, servlets

I am a newbie in java and I want to display all the images from a system folder, viz. E://New

I am using a servlet but don't know how to proceed using it.

The servlet is:

```
response.setContentType("image/jpeg");  

ServletOutputStream out;  
out = response.getOutputStream();  
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("E:\\new\\");  

BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);  
BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(out);  
int ch = 0; 
while((ch=bin.read())!=-1)  
{  
    bout.write(ch);  
}  

bin.close();  
fin.close();  
bout.close();  
out.close();
```

Thanks.

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300847/load-and-display-all-the-images-from-a-folder

Comment: `FileInputStream` is to take in data in a text format. It cannot be used to enumerate files found in a folder. Try using the method `listFiles()` found under the class `File` for that.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be made by this code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        response.setContentType("image/jpeg");

        String pathToWeb = getServletContext().getRealPath(File.separator);
        File f = new File(pathToWebToyourfile);
        BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(f);
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(bi, "jpg", out);
        out.close();

    }
```