# Showing all images from a directory of android storage in android recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-camera, android-file

**I am saving photo in a directory and I want to show them all in recyclerView with showing all info of image in TextView**

There is my codes 
MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    RecyclerView rec;
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter;
    List<Items> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        rec= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recView);

        File fi = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PhotosOfSalman");
        if (fi.isDirectory()) {  
            rec.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

            recyclerViewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(list);
            rec.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);




        }else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Nothing to show",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }





        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 000);


            }
        });
    }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if the result is capturing Image
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                 savePhoto(bitmap);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //Show


            }
        }
    }

    public void savePhoto(Bitmap bitmap){
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
        String  name = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());

        String  directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File folder = new File(directory+"/PhotosOfSalman");
        folder.mkdirs();

        File myFile = new File(folder,name+".JPEG");

        try {
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,80,stream);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Recycler View Adapter Class :-

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {

    List<Items> list;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Items> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


        Items items=list.get(position);

          holder.name.setText(items.getName());
        holder.date.setText(items.getDate());
        holder.size.setText(items.getSize());
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(items.getImage());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

Items Class :-

```
public class Items {


    Bitmap image;
    String name;
    String date;
    String size;

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(String size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public Items() {

    }

    public Items(Bitmap image, String name, String date, String size) {

        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

Any help?

Comment: So, you have a small program and it is doing.... something? What is the specific question?

Comment: no..actually I want to show image in recyclerView from a directory where are my images are saved...

Comment: how to fetch all images from a directory and show it in recyclerView

Comment: But what is your problem? All we see here is that you have some code that may or may not work. That's not a question, that's a story. BTW, details should be in the body of the question, not comments.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11301085/5516760