# Android Display Images from directory

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dynamic, android-imageview

I am trying to display images from a specified directory on an android device in a gallery type activity. i was following (at least trying to) the guide on displaying images on the android developers site but kept getting lost  http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html . I currently have a downsampled version of the image and am loading it into an image view in the layout.xml file. but this would require me to know the amount of images that will be present which i wont and i fear it is wasteful.

I need to Know how to create the image views depending on how many images are in the directory. and display the thumbnails or downsampled images in the created imageViews.

**layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
       tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView android:text="Hello World!" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/mImageView0"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    ............
    <ImageView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mImageView5"
        android:layout_below="@id/mImageView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final String TAG = "MainActivity Class";

    public ImageView mImageView;
    public ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String fileDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ File.separator +"Camera-App-Images"+ File.separator;
        File f = new File(fileDir);
        Log.d(TAG, fileDir);
        File file[] = f.listFiles();

        ImageView[] imgViews = new ImageView[file.length];

        for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++) {
            mImageView =  (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mImageView0 + i);
            listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
            loadBitmap(fileDir + file[i].getName(), mImageView);
        }
    }

    public void loadBitmap(String fileLoc, ImageView imageView) {
        BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(fileLoc ,imageView);
        task.execute();
    }
}
```

**BitmapWorkerTask**

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
    private int data = 0;

    private String imagePath = "";

    private final String TAG = "BitmapWorkerTask";

    public BitmapWorkerTask(String imgPath, ImageView imageView) {
        imagePath = imgPath;
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);

        Log.d(TAG,"Constructor");
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
         //data = params[0];
         return decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(imagePath, 100, 100);
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
             final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
             if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(String filePath, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

         if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you creating the imageviews statically in the xml? You should be doing this with a ListView or a Gridview and feed the list of images with an adapter...

Comment: @Mikel Thanks for your reply. i tried creating a class that extends ArrayAdapter and it was adding to my confusion. should  I be calling the adapter for each file in my array of files?

Comment: Use [these](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) examples to create your views and adapters and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7793015/562840) answer for getting the images.

Comment: Thank you ill have a look at them